# Accessing specific children

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<Parent>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
</Parent>
```

And in Parent's render's return I do:

```
{children && cloneElement(children, {onChange: this.onChange})}
```

Now let's say I want different callbacks for different cihldren. So are the followings the react way of doing it, or is there something else?

```
{children && children[0] && cloneElement(children[0], {onChange: onChange1})}
{children && children.length > 0 && children[1] && cloneElement(children[1], {onChange: onChange2})}
```

Or maybe something like that:

```
children.map(child => child.type.name === 'Child1' ? ... : ...)
```

Comment: you can use react's children utility and `map` over the children `React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {...}` and inside the callback check the type of child `if (child.type === 'Child1') ...`

Comment: Yea I just checked that as you wrote. Is it good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you if you want to give different callbacks to different children then you might as well move the child components within the parent component like

```
class Parent extend React.Component{
   render() {
      <div>
          {/*other elements*/}
           <Child1 onChange={this.onChange1}/>
           <Child2 onChange={this.onChange2}/>
      </div>
   }
}
```

Comment: So, is this the preferred pattern, because I wanted to organize my main components in one place?

Comment: You would generally clone the child element and pass props on to them if all of them need the same props, if not then its ideal to render them inside the components or move the event handlers up

Comment: Yea, right, it also has better readability. I ended up doing like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply avoid checking children and it's length check:

```
{children[1] && cloneElement(children[1], {onChange: onChange2})}
```

Because it will check for children[1] is returning true then cloneElement.

And if you want to use map, then you can use switch outside the render return statement:

```
render() {
  let child;
  switch(children) {
    case 'Child1':
      // ...
     // return child = ...
    default: 
     // ...
   }
  return (
    <div>
    {
      child.map(el=>el)
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or, even: (I know, you know it. Just kept here for prosperity)

```
return child ? ... : ...
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Right, other checks were redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react's children utility](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) and map over the children:

```js
const Child1 = () => 'Hi ';
const Child2 = () => ' There';

const Parent = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {
      React.Children.map(children, (Child) => {
        console.log('The child name is - ',Child.type.name)
        // return whatever you need here...
      })
    }
  </div>
);

const App = ({ children }) => (
  <Parent>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
  </Parent>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
```